# mapper function is always needed in a mapreduce program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

Im trying to develop a hadoop mapreduce program to calculate the maximum temperature inside a text file.

The input text file looks like this:

City1 - 10

City2 - 15

City3 - 4

city4 - 20

Im beginner in mapreduce, but I read that with mapper, the output should be the input transformed in meaningful key value pairs. But If I already have a input file like below, I dont need to write a mapper file (because is already with key value pairs)??

City1 10

City2 15

City3 4

city 4 10

I was trying to develop the mapper file but Im not understanding if its really necessary in this case.

Code:

```
for line in sys.stdin:

    line = line.strip()
    print line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is always needed. The mapper is only there to guarantee that the reducer receives sorted and partitioned input.

It's a framework design choice, Hadoop requires your mapper to be set. In your example you can use the standard `Mapper` / `IdentityMapper`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is possible you give me a help to put mapper working so I can understand the output result? Or the steps I need to do, because I'm not understanding what I have to do in this mapper.py file if I already have the data in that format!

Comment: You can simply use a Java mapper while submitting the job: `-mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper` read more here: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#Specifying+a+Java+Class+as+the+Mapper%2FReducer

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. Im using python, so the code for this mapper  would be just the code that I have in my question?

Comment: Thanks for your help, just one more question, you said that mapper guarantee that the reducer receives sorted input, but In my mapper Im not doing any sort. That sort is automatic when we use hadoop?